# Dirichlet series for square root of Riemann Zeta function

Tags: calculus, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series

Can we obtain Dirichlet series for the function $\sqrt{\zeta(s)}$? Is it possible via Euler product for $\zeta(s)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a solution then it will be the product of the Dirichlet series of   terms $(a_n)_{n\ge 1}$ with itself and thus have to verify the [Dirichlet convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution) $\;\displaystyle\sum_{d|n}\;a_d\cdot a_{n/d}=1$.

From this we obtain $\,a_1=1\,$ and $\ \ \displaystyle 2\cdot a_n=1-\sum_{d|n,d>1,d<n}\;a_d\cdot a_{n/d},\ \ n>1$ and thus :

$$\sqrt{\zeta(s)}=1+\frac 1{2\cdot 2^s}+\frac 1{2\cdot 3^s}+\frac 3{8\cdot 4^s}+\frac 1{2\cdot 5^s}+\frac 1{4\cdot 6^s}+\frac 1{2\cdot 7^s}+\frac 5{16\cdot 8^s}+\frac 3{8\cdot 9^s}+\frac 1{4\cdot 10^s}\\+\frac 1{2\cdot 11^s}+\frac 3{16\cdot 12^s}+\frac 1{2\cdot 13^s}+\frac 1{4\cdot 14^s}+\frac 1{4\cdot 15^s}+\frac {35}{128\cdot 16^s}+\frac 1{2\cdot 17^s}+\frac 3{16\cdot 18^s}+\cdots$$

Which is [OEIS A046643](https://oeis.org/A046643)  and [A046644](https://oeis.org/A046644) for the numerators and denominators with more references.

---

For fun let's add the expansion of the cube root :
$$\sqrt[3]{\zeta(s)}=1+\frac 1{3\cdot 2^s}+\frac 1{3\cdot 3^s}+\frac 2{9\cdot 4^s}+\frac 1{3\cdot 5^s}+\frac 1{9\cdot 6^s}+\frac 1{3\cdot 7^s}+\frac {14}{81\cdot 8^s}+\frac 2{9\cdot 9^s}+\frac 1{9\cdot 10^s}+\frac 1{3\cdot 11^s}+\frac 2{27\cdot 12^s}+\frac 1{3\cdot 13^s}+\frac 1{9\cdot 14^s}+\frac 1{9\cdot 15^s}+\frac {35}{243\cdot 16^s}+\frac 1{3\cdot 17^s}+\frac 2{27\cdot 18^s}+\cdots$$
quartic root :
$$\sqrt[4]{\zeta(s)}=1+\frac 1{4\cdot 2^s}+\frac 1{4\cdot 3^s}+\frac 5{32\cdot 4^s}+\frac 1{4\cdot 5^s}+\frac 1{16\cdot 6^s}+\frac 1{4\cdot 7^s}+\frac {15}{128\cdot 8^s}+\frac 5{32\cdot 9^s}\\+\frac 1{16\cdot 10^s}+\frac 1{4\cdot 11^s}+\frac 5{128\cdot 12^s}+\frac 1{4\cdot 13^s}+\frac 1{16\cdot 14^s}+\frac 1{16\cdot 15^s}+\frac{195}{2048\cdot 16^s}+\frac 1{4\cdot 17^s}+..$$
and quintic root :
$$\sqrt[5]{\zeta(s)}=1+\frac 1{5\cdot 2^s}+\frac 1{5\cdot 3^s}+\frac 3{25\cdot 4^s}+\frac 1{5\cdot 5^s}+\frac 1{25\cdot 6^s}+\frac 1{5\cdot 7^s}+\frac {11}{125\cdot 8^s}+\frac 3{25\cdot 9^s}+\frac 1{25\cdot 10^s}+\frac 1{5\cdot 11^s}+\frac 3{125\cdot 12^s}+\frac 1{5\cdot 13^s}+\frac 1{25\cdot 14^s}+\frac 1{25\cdot 15^s}+\frac {44}{625\cdot 16^s}+\frac 1{5\cdot 17^s}+.$$
$$ $$
**Interesting!** In fact the coefficient of the $k$-term of the Dirichet series for $\,\sqrt[N]{\zeta(s)}\,$ appears to be :

- $\displaystyle\dfrac 1{N^d}\quad$ if $k$ is the product of $d$ distinct primes.
- $\displaystyle\dfrac {\prod_{i=1}^{m-1} N+\frac 1i}{m\,N^m}\quad$ if $k$ is the $m$-th power of a prime ($m>1$).
- a product of the previous ones for products of powers of distinct primes !?

Comment: This conjecture appears right and related to multiplicative partitions as in the linked [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2329126) : the $k$-th term of the Dirichlet series $\,\displaystyle\zeta(s)^a\,$ with $\,a\,$ a positive real is the product of $a$ for every single prime in the factorization of $k$ and $\,\displaystyle\frac am \prod_{i=1}^{m-1} 1+\frac ai\;$ terms for every prime to the power $m$ of the factorization of $k$ (in the answer $a=\frac 1N$).

Comment: (the expression for the $m$-th power of a prime is simply $\,\displaystyle \frac{a^{\overline m}}{m!}=\binom {a+m-1} m \,$)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way is to use Taylor series:
$$
\sqrt {\zeta (s)}  = \sqrt {1 + (\zeta (s) - 1)}  = 1 + \frac{1}{2}(\zeta (s) - 1) - \frac{1}{8}(\zeta (s) - 1)^2  +  \cdots .
$$
Now just substitute the Dirichlet series of the zeta function into this expansion, re-expand it and collect the terms involving $\frac{1}{n^s}$.

Comment: +1: Interesting method, thanks to share! Cheers,

Answer (score 3):

$$F(s)=\prod_p (1+\sum_{k\ge 1} {-1/2\choose k}(-1)^kp^{-sk})=\sum_{n\ge 1} a_nn^{-s}$$
is the unique Dirichlet series such that $F(s)^2=\zeta(s)$ and $F(\infty)=1$. It converges for $\Re(s) > 1$. It has an awful branch point at $s=1$ making the asymptotic of $\sum_{n\le x} a_n$ complicated.